# mysql views get increased by 2 instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql, image, cloudflare

I own a image hosting website and I capture image views using php and mysql.

I use the following code to count the views.

```
include_once'mysql.php';
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE DB SET views=(views+1) WHERE ID='$id'") or die;
mysql_close($con);
```

mysql `use P_Connect` function to connect.

views is `mediumint(9)` type field.

I noticed that the views get increased by 2 instead of 1.can anyone say what is the problem and offer a solution.

also I use **CloudFlare** to cache the pages maybe it is causing it,if that's the error can someone give the code to bypass their views..

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this updated? img tag or page with the image on it?

Comment: your sql query is correct, so problem is in some other part of the code. If you rely want somebody to help you provide more info when you not sure where the problem can be.

Comment: Code looks right, check any redirects if you have them.

Comment: You do appear to have a JS error on you're site when viewing an image - this may be causing a re-load...   SyntaxError: missing } after property list
[Break On This Error]  

backdrop: true;

/view/...404863/ (line 201, col 22)
 
which is: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#event-modal').modal({
backdrop: true;
});
});
</script>

Comment: **warning** your code maybe vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is looking correct. **May be this query is running twice due to some other code effect** so please  **print this query with exit. and try to run manually** ,and check If it working properly there mean there is issue in some other code.

thanks

Comment: I totally forgot I asked this question. After a while, during a code review of the said page, I found the same mysql query on the page. so what happened was, when I tested the page, it increased the count once and again when I viewed the image.